# reducing json string size by shortening variable names

Tags: javascript, asp.net, json

I have some json formatted data that I parse with JSON.parse. The problem I have is with the length of the varialble names:

```
MyObjectName.SuperLongPropertyName;
MyObjectName.AnotherLongPropertyName;
```

and so on. I'm using JavascriptSerializer and a custom JavascriptConverter to generate the json. It's used in several ajax calls and the data is about 70K.

However, if I could change the variable to

```
   a.a;
   a.b;
```

that could shave off half the size of the json string.

I can easily change the serialization/deserialization classes on the server. However, on the client-side, it'd be more tricky because I'm using these objects everywhere in my code. And then, even if I do manage to change the variable name, it'd then become pretty difficult code to debug in a javascript debugger.

What are some good suggestions to a) convert my existing variable names on the client, and b) maintain readability and debuggability?

Thanks.

Comment: The real questions is, why would you want shorter json strings. Are you sending that much data? 70k on its own isn't that shocking

Comment: You could build a sorted map (by number of occurrences) of property names and short names. Rewrite the json with those shorter names and send the map + json. ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [transparent HTTP gzip compression](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec3.html#sec3.5). Your server then compresses the sent data on-the-fly, and the web browser decodes it again.

gzip does precisely what you suggested, *only better*. Instead of picking static aliases for some long repeating names, gzip picks aliasses for all names, and assigns the shortest ones to the aliasses which occur most. Also, gzip doesn't care about syntax, and can therefore assign `, "SuperLongName": {` (including punctuation and spaces) to a single symbol.

Comment: ok, let me see if how this works with azure... I was hoping for a more programmatic option but gzip might work better after all.